# angular-bootstrap datepicker, how to change disabled dates style?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I'm using angular-bootstrap datepicker to popup a calendar with available and *not available* dates.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r0V5R9dcboOUFmO5qMtK?p=preview)...

The style of previous and next month dates is a bit more 'faint' than disabled days, but disabled days are quite indistinguishable from enabled ones...

Is it possible to control the style of disabled / enabled dates? I'm struggling with 'btn-info.disabled' class, with little success... :-( I would like to put - for example - some graduation of red in the background of disabled dates...

I think the relevant part of angular-ui-bootstrap (Version 0.10.0) file "ui-bootstrap-tpls.js" is:

```
angular.module("template/datepicker/datepicker.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/datepicker/datepicker.html",
    "<table>\n" +
    "  <thead>\n" +
    "    <tr>\n" +
    "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left\" ng-click=\"move(-1)\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></i></button></th>\n" +
    "      <th colspan=\"{{rows[0].length - 2 + showWeekNumbers}}\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block\" ng-click=\"toggleMode()\"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button></th>\n" +
    "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right\" ng-click=\"move(1)\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></i></button></th>\n" +
    "    </tr>\n" +
    "    <tr ng-show=\"labels.length > 0\" class=\"h6\">\n" +
    "      <th ng-show=\"showWeekNumbers\" class=\"text-center\">#</th>\n" +
    "      <th ng-repeat=\"label in labels\" class=\"text-center\">{{label}}</th>\n" +
    "    </tr>\n" +
    "  </thead>\n" +
    "  <tbody>\n" +
    "    <tr ng-repeat=\"row in rows\">\n" +
    "      <td ng-show=\"showWeekNumbers\" class=\"text-center\"><em>{{ getWeekNumber(row) }}</em></td>\n" +
    "      <td ng-repeat=\"dt in row\" class=\"text-center\">\n" +
    "        <button type=\"button\" style=\"width:100%;\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\" ng-class=\"{'btn-info': dt.selected}\" ng-click=\"select(dt.date)\" ng-disabled=\"dt.disabled\" datepicker-disabled=\"dt.disabled\"><span ng-class=\"{'text-muted': dt.secondary}\">{{dt.label}}</span></button>\n" +
    "      </td>\n" +
    "    </tr>\n" +
    "  </tbody>\n" +
    "</table>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```

Did anybody face and/or solve this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my own question, if anybody cares... :-)

I did finally "solve" with this css hack, in my form's css:

```
.btn[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.90;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  background-color: #690000;
  color: #777;
}
```

This colors with a dark red background the disabled dates... I feel this simplify the datepicker usage, when disabled dates can be a lot, and not only in the past...

Answer (score 1):

I would just override the style with an external style sheet, that way you will not be changing the UI bootsrap, important if you want other devs to reuse the library.

In terms of css the disabled colour inherits from the `.btn-default` style where as the background of the disabled date is the same as the non disabled ones.

What I would do is override the style for 'text-muted' which is applied to the disabled dates.

Comment: Thanks. That's for sure... But I don't know what to write in the new css... :-)

Comment: Trying just now... It seems that 'text-muted' class is used by datepicker for days of previous/next month, and not for disabled ones... BTW, thanks!

Comment: heres a plunker that you can share your solution with its a bit more fidgety than I first thought with all the ng-class stuff, http://plnkr.co/edit/DAIFxCNGnGvP0eQ4MXZ7?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot, it should have been my job... :-) I did update your plunk to show my use-case (I link it in the question...). Disabled dates are not selectable, but not visually clearly distinguishable from enabled ones... :-)